# Unable to run game after unity generates source code for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, unity-game-engine

I am new on iphone game dev. Game engine I am using is unity 3D, I am making a sample game to initiate development. I have cracked unity3.4 for iphone and ipad, now it generates code for iphone in obj.c its cool but I am unable to run it neither on device nor on simulator. I havent yet purchased apple developer account yet. Here is the error I am getting:

**Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain**

What should I do now ? Is there any way I would make it run on device/simulator.
Is this problem is about account purchasing or anything else ? Pls give me solution for this.
Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: in player settings of unity, select iOS Simulator :)